# Informatica SQ returns different result

Tags: db2, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to pull data from DB2 via informatica, I have a SQ query that pulls few fields based on joins for 4 different tables.

When I run the query directly in the database, it returns the expected result, however when I run it in informatica and run a debugger, I see something else.
Please note all the columns data perfectly match, except one single column.

Weird thing is, this is a calculated field from the table based on a case statement:

```
CASE WHEN Column1='3' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END.
```

Since this is a calculated field with a length of one string, I have connected from the source to SQ from one of the sources having 1 character length.

This returns 'Y' when executed in the database, the same query when I copy paste in SQ of information and run it, I get a data 'E', and this data can never be possible as I expect only a N or a Y. I have verified the column order, that its in the right place. This is very strange, is something going wrong because of the CASE Statement?

Comment: Please post the full sql override query and the exact list of column in order

Comment: Ah I found the error. When the case statement evaluates to a Y in informatica the value shown is E8 similarly when the case evaluates to N the value in informatica is D5, and this is the HEX equivalent.

Comment: I guess something is wrong with my SQ itself.

Comment: @RaghavRao - sounds like it's getting converted to a `byte` at some point.  Do you have a `CAST` or something in there?

Comment: No.this field is just a case statement exactly as I specified : CASE WHEN Column1='3' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END. As it's flag it's one length character string, so intially it was getting truncate with only one character i.e E for E8. I increase length to see what data I get. Probably because the souce field name and the SQ fieldname is different.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the hassle, put an expression transformation after tge source qualifier and calculate, port value there then forget about it

Comment: The thing is, in my SQ i am using analytical function like a ROW_NUMBER, and then later grouping by this particular case statement field. the field column1 has multiple entries, and if i do not apply the case statement at the db level, i will have multiple rows at informatica, and purpose of this is to remove the requirement of using an aggregator in informatica, i want performance. Its really strange that when i execute the same query in DB2, i get the flag 'Y', but when i run the debugger, as soon as the data is returned at SQ, i see the value "E8"

Comment: and its strange that its happening only for this particular field. Instead of a case statement, if i just pass the column 1, i get the data as string. Just want to somehow find out, why is applying a case statement affecting the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the issue. We use Informatica PowerExchange to connect to a as400 system(DB2), and it seems that when we are trying to set a flag information in AS400, and pass it to informatica via PowerExchange, it converts it to binary, and to solve this, there needs to be an entry in the PowerExchange configuration file.

Unfortunately, i myself was not aware that it could be related to PowerExchange instead of powercenter itself.!!

Thanks for your assistance! Below is the KB about it.

https://kb.informatica.com/solution/4/Pages/17498.aspx